# Store plugin page content in wp_options?

Tags: plugins, wpdb, options

I want to write a plugin for wordpress that in some cases will show some content as if it were a post or page as an end result of a form processing.

My idea is to add a hook that checks for and intercepts a GET or POST request from a form, and when processed, shows some message as a post/page.

As I wish to be anble to change the text, I would like to have a plugin page that has the text editor and store the result from this in the database for when needed.

My question is then: should such a message, which is in the end a post/page be written to wp_options, or is there a better aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering short: it's legit and proper solution.

Answering in details:

**1. About the table capacity**

Considering `_options` table structure

```
option_id    | bigint(20)
option_name  | varchar(64)
option_value | longtext
autoload     | varchar(20)
```

and the fact that `option_value` (which is going to contain your HTML), is [`longtext`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) - it can store `L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32`  (4 Gigabytes of info).

I'd like to say more: serialized array, which can contain options stored as a text, is much more effective THAN `key-value` pairs in terms of db optimization (understand as storing a short strings under `meta/option_name - meta/option_value`, is less effective).

**2. About storing the HTML**

Dont forget about charaters escaping there.

`<?php echo stripslashes( get_option( 'your_option' ) ); ?>`, in order to output the content.

More advanced solution may be a serialized array. But it's more suitable if you want to store some `key-value` "option" pairs additionally to your HTML.

**3. The API.**

`_options` table can be accessed via user-friendly API

1. [`get_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
2. [`add_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)
3. [`update_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)